# Image resize issue in Mozilla Firefox for windows

Tags: image, firefox, png

I am having some weird issues. I have a large image which is being shrunk to size 30px in the img link so:

```
img src="/company/images/logos/1.png" height="30px"
```

On all browsers and computers it looks fine except for firefox on a windows.  I found out that when i rid the height constraint it looks fine but when i add the "30px" it looks messed up.

Any ideas on what i might need to do?

Comment: How is it "messed up"? Is there a resizing issue, or a placement issue, or something else? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: Also, the number for the "height" attribute should be unitless, i.e. not "30px" but simply "30".

Comment: @tkm256 i have tried both variations.

Comment: ya im having the same issue and i cant seem to find a solution... guess ill just resize the actual image file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about issue where the default Firefox image resizing algorithm makes the image look "jagged".

In general, it's better to not let the browser resize the image.

**You should instead make a version of the image that is already the correct size.**

I'm not aware of a way to make the image look good when downscaling in Firefox.

[**See here for a comparison.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JNtwR/) *(I used Firefox 3.6.15 / Windows 7)*

If anybody has a way to make the first image downscale smoothly in Firefox, I'd like to know.